# Retrofit, callback for 204 No Content response?

Tags: android, retrofit, http-status-code-204

On Android, I initially implemented a Retrofit interface like this:

```
@DELETE(USER_API_BASE_URL + "/{id}")
public void deleteUser(@Path("id") String id, Callback<User> callback);
```

The server returns 204 NO CONTENT upon a successful deletion. This was causing the callback to trigger failure, with `retrofit.RetrofitError: End of input at character 0 of`, as it was expecting a `User` object back with the response.

I then rewrote it like this, using `Void` instead of `User`:

```
@DELETE(USER_API_BASE_URL + "/{id}")
public void deleteUser(@Path("id") String id, Callback<Void> callback);  <-- VOID
```

But I am getting the same error from the callback.
What is the proper way to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: How Retrofit can make `User` when ther's no content in response? Why you want `User` object back, when it was already deleted?

Comment: Does it work with Callback<Response>? Also what version of retrofit do you use?

Comment: hey Volodymyr, it does work. It doesn't feel like the proper way tho -- the signature of the callback's success method is then `public void success(Response response1, Response response) {..}` which looks a bit weird.

Comment: You can use a `ResponseCallback` for that.

Comment: thanks Jake. Solving this question.

Comment: @ticofab How did you solved this problem. I am receiving this issue 
nterface method 'java.io.InputStream retrofit.mime.TypedInput.in()' on a null object reference. Could you please help me with this

Comment: @AkshayMukadam I solved it the way is indicated in 2 comments above and one answer below :) use `ResponseCallback`.

Comment: @ticofab I am trying Uber API I am receiving the above error

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Retrofit 2.x` no longer has a `ResponseCallback` as mentioned in the other answer.  You want to use a `Response<Void>` type.

The RxJava declaration:

```
@PUT Observable<Response<Void>> foo();
```

The standard declaration:

```
@PUT Call<Response<Void>> bar();
```

Comment: But the problem is even if the web service call has an error, it executes success block and not the throwable block

Comment: I am getting " Cannot serialize abstract class okhttp3.ResponseBody" with retrofit and moshi 2.3.0

Comment: @GregEnnis You're using the wrong type, it's Response from `retrofit2.Response`

Comment: @SammyPatenotte actually this answer is obsolete. In retrofit 2.3.0 using just PUT Call<Void> bar() works as expected; no need for Response<> return type.

Comment: Mmh that's weird, in my case it doesn't work with only Void, but I'm using it for POST requests, so I'm not sure if that is the reason why

Comment: @MobileMon I have the same problem, when there is error from the server, the success block is called but not the throwable, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: This answer works out for `@DELETE` for server returning 204. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The solution was pointed out by Jake Wharton in the comments. Use ResponseCallback.

**EDIT:** this response is no longer valid for Retrofit < 2.

Comment: Hey guys, the link in this answer was invalid. -_-|||

Answer (score 1):

This is the kotlin way for the implementation to deal with HTTP 204 and no content.

```
@DELETE(USER_API_BASE_URL + "/{id}")
suspend fun deleteuser(@HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>, 
                       @Path("id") id: String)
: Response<Void>
```

Comment: Using `Response<Void>` will be successful for 204 code but will be also successful for 400 code, the throwable block won't be called for 4xx code responses